# Can I Generate an .hprof heap format in WebSphere?

Tags: java, websphere, heap-dump

Is there any way to generate an .hprof heap dump format using WebSphere application server instead of generating .phd format ??

because IBM .phd heap format isn't full, it's just contain the object names without its value.

Answer (score 1):

You can't generate an hprof dump, but you can generate a system dump. This has object values, and quite a bit else as well. The JVM option which enables this is '-Xdump:system'. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21597830 has more information and examples of collecting various kinds of dumps with WebSphere 8.5 Liberty profile.